# Pull log data from diverse logging sources

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, graylog

We have an environment with linux and windows servers, different cisco components and netapp storage technologies. We want to implement a central logging infrastructure (like graylog or ELK stack) and one requirement is to use the pull method for log data collection. Is using an agent considered a pull method, since the agent monitors log files for changes and then sends them? What other pull method is there that can be used to retrieve data from so many different sources and what products provide this functionality?

Comment: The ability to _pull_ a log depends entirely on the source, normally pulling a log means that you have your logs on a service that accept requests to send the logs, something like Kafka, a Database or an API, the other way to get logs is pushing the logs using an agent or some configuration, for example having an agent reading log files and shipping them. Not everything has the ability to have the logs pulled, network devices for example normally only ship logs to syslog servers. How you will get the logs depend on the source and your limitations. Can you explain why you can only use pull?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using a pull method is a requirement in the security framework we are using (IT Baseline Protection by the German cyber security agency BSI). Authenticity of log files seems to be one of the reasons why they want you to use the pull method.

Comment: I suspected something like that. This will depend on the sources of logs, you can't pull logs if this is not supported by the source of the log, which is the case of most applications and devices, so you need to check what you are allowed to do in that cases.

Comment: Yes, I think we'll go ahead and check which sources support pulling data and then just use agents for those who don't. I believe we at least have to show that we tried. Thanks again for your help.